# Construction of relative projective space via glueing

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, projective-space, projective-schemes

I would like to gain further practice on glueing schemes by constructing projective space over a ring. I am considering the following:

[image]

I wonder how we get that $\mathcal{O}_{X_i} (X_{ij}) = \mathcal{O}_{X_j}(X_{ji})$ implies there is such a canonical isomorphism, which I shall call $f_{ij}$. I know that $\textrm{Hom} (X,Y) = \textrm{Hom} (\mathcal{O}_Y (Y), \mathcal{O} _X (X))$ and it seems to be related except those are global sections.

Next, there are additional conditions to check when glueing, namely

> $f_{ij} (X_{ij} \cap X_{ik}) = X_{ji} \cap X_{jk}$ and $f_{ij} = f_{jk} \circ f_{ij}$ on $X_{ij} \cap X_{ik}$.

How can we verify these conditions?

Comment: Since $X_{ij}$ and $X_{ji}$ are open subsets of affine varieties $X_i$ and $X_j$ they are themselves affine varieties hence are characterized by their rings $O_{X_i}(X_{ij})$ and $O_{X_j}(X_{ji})$ of global sections, which coincide.  Glueing is checked again by writing down rings of global sections: for instance for $X_{ij}\cap X_{ik}$ we get $A[(T_i^{-1} T_l)_{1\leq l\leq n}, T_i T_j^{-1}, T_i T_k^{-1}]$ which coincides with the corresponding ring for $X_{ji}\cap X_{jk}$ (and the isomorphism is what was used to identify $O_{X_i}(X_{ij})$ and $O_{X_j}(X_{ji})$).

Comment: To build the projective space it is more convenient to use [the $\mathrm{Proj}\mathbb{A}[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$ construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proj_construction).